# How to move file/folder to a different depended project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I've got two projects: A and B. B is dependent on A.
Now I've got a package in B that I want to move into A. I would like to know what is the safe and correct way and keep all dependencies updated.

Thanks very much :)

PS: Now the dependence between A and B is already set. And for editing purpose of A maybe it's not good to make it a library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the package.

```
Refactor > Move
```

Select the destination project.

> Refactoring actions change the structure of your code without changing its semantic behavior.

[Eclipse :Moving and copying Java elements](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-10.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Just select the package --> Press Ctrl + C . Then go to the destination where you want to move the package --> Press Ctrl + V.

Comment: Yeah @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ , I think IDE perform refactoring automatically when you copy and paste.

Comment: @VimalBera Nope,It won't. At least for me it didn't.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ actually it happened with me one or two times. BTW thanks for informing about it. Otherwise I'll never know about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make A as Library(Check Is Library) and provide its reference in B.